# Pandas Resampling Daily Volume to Monthly with Date Ranges for Each DF Entry

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
start       end         loc   volume
12/1/2021  2/28/2022    A      10000
1/1/2022   1/31/2022    A      10000
12/1/2021  2/28/2022    B      5000
```

The volume is a daily volume at each location between the start and end dates.  I would like to complete a pivot style function (or remain in DF see below) to output average volume by month at each location.  Output would look like this:

```
             A      B
12/1/2021  10000   5000
1/1/2022   20000   5000
2/1/2022   10000   5000
```

I have the following code, which is working:

```
df["GroupDate"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x["start"], x["end"]), axis=1)
df = (df.explode("GroupDate", ignore_index=True))
df = df.groupby(by=['GroupDate','loc']).sum().reset_index()
df.pivot(index='GroupDate', columns='loc', values='volume').resample('MS').mean()
```

**My question is, am I missing a more efficient way to do this?**  I can see the date range for each DF entry is like many daily entries compressed into one line as it is a daily volume, but it feels inefficient (and memory intensive) to explode the DF to daily entries just so I can combine it back into monthly averages.

Also, is there someway to handle a multi-index while pivoting/resampling?  In these steps:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['GroupDate','loc']).sum()
df = df.resample('MS').mean()
```

If I don't reset the index like in the first code block, I get a:

`Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'`

Error.  I'm not totally sure whats happening with the data there.  I would have thought I got a daily entry for each "loc" in DF format, that I could then pivot how I wanted.  Not sure why it stalls here - obviously pandas doesn't like the multi-index, but is there a way to get this data in a DF instead of the method I use in my first code block?

Thank you

Comment: You can specify the [`level`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) of a multiIndex, i.e. `df.resample('MS', level=0)`.